# How to include extern typdedef struct in a file that contains the header file where the struct is defined in C?

Tags: c, struct, extern

I have three files, `libsched.c`, `main.c` and `libgrapher.c` and their headers `*.h`

`libsched.h` define `typedef struct p{.....}process;` then `main.c` uses  `libsched.h`.
Then I have another file `libgrapher.c` which uses `process` defined in `libsched.h`.

How can I tell `libsched.h` that `process` exists in `libsched.h` without including `libsched.h` in `libgrapher.h`.

Redefine the `struct` in `libgrapher.h` gives me an error that it is redefined.

Comment: You can [edit] your post to clarify/fix errors. Why don't you want to include the first header in the second?

Comment: Please edit your post and put in proper details so that we can help

Comment: Guys Thank you for the comments. I have figured out the problem now. The best way to solve this problem is to use macros. "#ifndef [whatever]; #define [whatever]; struct p{.....}process; #endif; Include this in both the header files.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements don't make any sense. Either libgrapher.h needs access to everything in libsched.h and then it should include that header file. Or if it shouldn't have access to everything in that h file but just parts of it, then you need to split the h file in two.

Strange requirements and the need of obscure tricks to dodge various file dependencies always originate from poor program design. Whenever you find yourself needing things like this, step back and re-consider your program design.

Answer (score 1):

You can do e.g.

```
typedef struct p process;
```

That declaration tells the compiler both that there is a structure named `p` ad that there's a type-alias for `struct p` named `process`.

This will work as long as you only user pointers to `process`.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use this (incomplete type) in the file including the header where the type definition is located? That would create a very strange dependency between the two files, like doing OO design backwards.

Answer (score 0):

The only option is an incomplete type definition, but that would make your files depend on each other in a bad way. There is nothing wrong with including other headers in your header.